# error TS: 2339 Property "Project" does not exist on type { }

Tags: javascript, angular, crossfilter

I am using crossfilter js library in my Angular 2 + project, 
As per documentation of crossfilter, Crossfilter API accepts array of javascript objects.
Using a service I am getting data from mongo db, using observable I am getting data in form of array of Object.

below is service call in my component

```
this._getdataservice.getData().subscribe(  
    function (posts) {
        console.log(posts);
        var ndx = crossfilter(posts);
        var projectDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.Project });
    }
)
```

I am Getting error as shown in below screen shot
[image]

If I print post object in console it is giving array of object

[image]

Code written in service

```
getData(): Observable<any>  {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
}
```

code written in component in which service is injected

```
constructor(private _getdataservice: DataServiceService) { }

ngOnInit() { 
    this._getdataservice.getData().subscribe(function(posts){
        console.log(posts);
        var ndx = crossfilter(posts);
        var projectDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Project});
    })
}
```

Please help me to understand where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type of **`d`** as **`any`**

```
var projectDim = ndx.dimension(function(d : any) { return d.Project};
```

Comment: thank You very much. Why does it work? Could You explain?